# Android TalkBack focuses behind a transparent layer

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have a transparent view in my app on top of a few fragments. So my fragments are below the transparent overlay, but they are not reachable by the user while the overlay is opened, as touching the overlay will dismiss it. All work fine up to the point when I enable TalkBack

My problem is that when I have TalkBack enabled and I swipe to select the next element, once TalkBack has finished with everything in the overlay, it will start setting focus on items below overlay. Is there any way to stop it from doing so? Something similar to the `android:clickable="true"` or using an onClick listener for making the transparent overlay intercept all clicks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On API 19+, you can set the [accessibility importance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setImportantForAccessibility(int)) of root view of the hierarchy that you want to hide from TalkBack to be [NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS). This will prevent TalkBack from focusing anything in that hierarchy, and this is how we handle the navigation drawer scrim.

On previous versions, there's no good way to accomplish this. There are some bad ways involving manually hiding nodes from the AccessibilityNodeInfo for the root view, though, and you can check those in the [DrawerLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java/) source code.

Comment: alanv, you are a star!!! I didn't know about NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS flag. Just to add to your answer, below API 19 one can use `ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(view,
                           ViewCompat.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);`

Comment: On API < 19, though, the compat method will translate to NO and only the root will be hidden -- the descendants will still be reachable. This is why we still have the AccessibilityDelegate hack in DrawerLayout.